# Python Path difference

Tags: python, macos

what is the difference between them?

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 

/usr/bin/python3

MacBook-Pro Desktop % whereis python3
/usr/bin/python3
MacBook-Pro Desktop % /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.9
MacBook-Pro Desktop % /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.9



>python3                                                      
Python 3.7.9 (v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 15 2020, 01:31:08) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from my_custom_module.__main__ import main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_custom_module'
```

**But it works with other**

```
>/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 
>>>from my_custom_module.__main__ import main
it works
```

There is weird thing happens I mean, when I type full path I get 3.8.8 but when I type short name "python3" I get 3.7.9.
though
whereis returns as follow

```
MacBook-Pro Desktop % whereis python3
/usr/bin/python3


/usr/bin/python3
Python 3.8.9 (default, Aug  3 2021, 19:21:54) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But

```
MacBook-Pro Desktop % python3         
Python 3.7.9 (v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 15 2020, 01:31:08) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
```

Comment: Each major version of python (3.1, 3.2, 3.3, etc.) has its own separate import path.  On your system, `python3` runs python 3.7.  The other command must run some other version.  You can run `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 --version` to find out.

Comment: I believe the former is coming with `CommandLineTools` in Mac which is usually installed with XCode. However, the latter is the default `python` comes with the operating system.

Comment: I have shared my investigations by editing questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion lies in the `whereis` command.  `whereis python3` doesn't actually tell you what will be run when you use `python3`, it just searches the standard binary directories for the specified program (`python3`).  I would recommend using `which` instead, as it searches the actual PATH that you use.

See [man page for whereis](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis), [man page for which](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which), [comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/40301/which-whereis-differences).

For example on my personal computer:

```
❯ whereis python3
/usr/bin/python3
❯ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
❯ /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.9
❯ /usr/local/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.9.7
❯ python3 --version
Python 3.9.7
```